# Skewed Grab or Scale in Edit Mode

Tags: edit-mode, transform-orientation

Just learning blender here. One problem I stumbled upon is expanding length of an object in Edit Mode, when that object's rotation is not aligned to global axis (e.g. rotation has been *applied*).

[image: Skewed cube with rotation applied]

Let's say I selected four vertices forming one side of a cube. **How can I grab the loop and move it without affecting the angles**? G-G to slide loop only works within dimensions of the cube (i.e. I can only "shrink" the object"). Assuming there's a face between those vertices I can select the face, use Transformation Orientation: Normal and move the face. But **what if there's no face**? Normals won't work for this, and none of the other orientations or pivot points seem to do the job either (understandably). Same problem applies to scaling but I suspect if there's a solution, it'll work for both cases.

[image: Trying to grab it without affecting angles]

Seems like it should be a pretty common thing to do when modelling complex objects, so what's the trick? For now my workaround is to create a temporary face between selected vertices and use Transformation Orientation: Normal, but I'm wondering if there's an easier or more "correct" way to do this (also it probably won't work if vertices are not forming a plane).

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> can actually extend edges beyond existing bounds.

**Either**: drag slightly inwards to establish the edges you're sliding along, and then hit <kbd>C</kbd> or hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while dragging outwards along the (now displayed) extended edges,

**Or** Go into the 'Adjust Last Operation' panel, and uncheck 'Clamp'

It's always worth checking operator options displayed at the bottom of the 3D View when you're getting to know new tools.. I'm still picking stuff up from there, even after using Blender for quite a long time.

Comment: Thanks. The only situation where this requires extra work is when the other end of the object (the one I move away from) doesn't form 90° angles with edges I'm sliding on. `E`-`F` doesn't work for this and neither unchecking 'Clamp' (the latter deforms moved loop). But I can make a temporary extra loop cut in between, parallel to the loop I'm grabbing and then it's doing what I want.

Comment: @Caleb9, you can also create a custom orientation from an edge.. then Y is the direction along its length.

Comment: Cool! That's probably the fastest and best way to do that :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow this procedure :

1. Select the back face of your object (who should have the same "normal" orientation than what you are trying to achieve), and go to the orientation menu, click the "+" icon. This will give you a custom orientation labelled "face", which will be active now.
   [image]
2. Now, with this custom orientation, just move your edges, vertices, or faces. They will follow the normal you are trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: I accept Robin Betts' answer because it covers scenario when there's no face on either end, or if there's no 90° angle between that face and the edges. But your method is also useful to know, so thanks. :)

Comment: Scratch the "no 90° angle" part, the loop gets deformed in that scenario.